# HTTP GET, from specific local IP, using alternate DNS

Tags: go, dns

First, newbie to Go.  Next, I am trying to run the following code below and experiencing this error

```
2021/06/16 18:24:15 Get "https://www.cnn.com": dial tcp: lookup www.cnn.com on 192.168.100.200:53: dial udp: address 192.168.100.65: mismatched local address type
exit status 1
```

My end goal is to use a predefined DNS server (alternate from the OS) and create a HTTP/S connection using a specific local IP address.  I also suspect this could be accomplished with less code, so would love to understand this more from someone more familiar with Go.

```
package main

import (
  "context"
  "io/ioutil"
  "log"
  "net"
  "net/http"
  "time"
)

func main() {

  q := net.ParseIP("192.168.100.65")
  addr := &net.IPAddr{q,""}

  var (
    dnsResolverIP        = "8.8.8.8:53" 
    dnsResolverProto     = "udp"        
    dnsResolverTimeoutMs = 5000         
  )

  dialer := &net.Dialer{
    Resolver: &net.Resolver {
      PreferGo: true,
      Dial: func(ctx context.Context, network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
        d := net.Dialer {
          LocalAddr: addr,  
          Timeout: time.Duration(dnsResolverTimeoutMs) * time.Millisecond,
        }
        return d.DialContext(ctx, dnsResolverProto, dnsResolverIP)
      },
    },
  }

  dialContext := func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return dialer.DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
  }

  http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).DialContext = dialContext
  httpClient := &http.Client{}

  // Testing the new HTTP client with the custom DNS resolver.
  resp, err := httpClient.Get("https://www.cnn.com")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
  }
  defer resp.Body.Close()

  body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
  }

  log.Println(string(body))
}
```

Comment: The local address has to be of type [*net.UDPAddr](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#UDPAddr), not *IPAddr, I think. Use zero for the port to have the OS pick a random local port.

Comment: The local address is for establishing a TCP connection, not UDP.  But I thought I needed to convert the IP address string using this?

Comment: I see now. You are using addr for both the DNS lookup and the TCP connection. I don't know if this is intentional or not, but you should be using specific address types for the protocol, *net.UDPAddr and/or *net.TCPAddr. IPAddr is for things using the lower-level IP protocol, such as ICMP.